# Primefaces 3.0 to 3.5 dialog does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The following code working in primefaces 3.0 does not work in 3.5.

**Error : dialog() does not exist on javascript** My query is dialog has been removed from dialog.js?? If so what is the alternative then?

```
function OpenDialog(currentDialog, commandSource) { 
    $(currentDialog).dialog('open');   
    var myDialogX = jQuery(commandSource).offset().left + 10;   
    var myDialogY = (jQuery(commandSource).offset().top - jQuery(document).scrollTop()) + 30;   
  //jQuery(currentDialog).dialog('option', 'position', [ myDialogX, myDialogY ]); 
}


    <p:commandLink id="treedialog-copy" 
        title="title" value="Copy tree"
        oncomplete="OpenDialog('#copyTree','#treedialog-copy')" /> 



    <p:outputPanel id="TreePanel">
        <p:dialog id="copyTree" header="Tree Dialog"
            styleClass="dlgAssignTree" modal="false" width="600" height="250" widgetVar="copyTrees">
            <h:form id="copyTreeForm">
                <p:outputPanel id="TreePanel">
                    <p:tree id="component2"
                        value="#{bean.provideTreeRootNode}" var="_node"
                        dynamic="true" cache="false" selectionMode="multiple"
                        selection="#{bean.selectedCopyNodes}">
                        <p:ajax event="select" 
                            listener="#{bean.onNodeSelectCopy}" />
                        <p:ajax event="unselect" 
                            listener="#{processBean.onNodeUnSelectCopy}" />
                        <p:treeNode>
                            <h:outputText value="#{_node.name}" />
                        </p:treeNode>
                    </p:tree>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Check the generated HTML ids for the `<p:dialog>` and the `<p:commandLink>` components by viewing the source of the page, I bet they're not `copyTree` nor `treedialog-copy` . It would be wise to use a JavaScript console like Firebug or Chrome console. Also, make sure that your `<p:dialog>` is outside the `<h:form>` that contains your `<p:commandLink id="treedialog-copy" />`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can directly crate a dialog box something like this..

```
 <p:commandButton id="basic" value="Basic" onclick="dlg1.show();" type="button" />  
    <p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1">  
        <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />  
    </p:dialog>
```

If you are using Primefaces then i dont thing we have to create a dialog box manually we can use their component it will increase productivity and bug fixing time